# Quotes vs Spoilers - Style Sheet Change

Tags: bug, design

In the past, quotes and spoilers had a yellow background (using the same color as watched tags). They were basically the same, except for whether or not they hid text.

As of sometime today, they both have a grey bar to the left:

> Like this.

But only spoilers have a background fill:

> Like this.

It is clear the style sheet has changed, but is this difference between two previously closer styles deliberate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a deliberate change, see [this main meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/343919/345161) where it was initially announced. Though the change appears to have only gone live in the past hour or so and I haven't seen an updated announcement *yet* stating it is live.

Comment: Ugh... but it is what it is. :(

Comment: @T.J.L. To be fair it looks better than I thought it was going to and not being yellow actually fits our "theme" better so some positives.

Comment: I suppose. I spend most of my time over on RPG.se, where the yellow stood out enough, but still themed in nicely. Funny that he specifically mentions that stack in the statement, though. I suppose it will stop people using it as a heading highlight.

Comment: It's still in yellow on mobile. It looks much better

Comment: @Valorum Not for me on iOS with Chrome. Probably a bug for you if it's still yellow.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot While I agree it fits better with our theme, it also looks damn ugly at the same time. I definitely preferred it when it was yellow ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Rebel-Scum it’d be better if it had a background to it still. Hopefully they’ll take user advice after the change cos they didn’t take it beforehand.